# Angular2: get reference of html element inside component and then Scroll to top that html element

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have this table inside my `TableComponent`:

```
<table #trackerTable>
```

I want to scroll to top of it when something happens so I try to reference it with inside my `TableComponent`:

```
@ViewChild("trackerTable") trackerTable;
```

and when `myMethod()` is triggered I try to `scrollTo(0,0)`:

```
public myMethod() {
    this.trackerTable.scrollTo(0,0); //  TypeError: this.trackerTable.scrollTo is not a function
}
```

But I get error:  `TypeError: this.trackerTable.scrollTo is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needed to add `ElementRef` to field and `nativeElement` in method, leaving answers for those who might need it:

```
@ViewChild("trackerTable") trackerTable: ElementRef;


public myMethod(): void {
    this.trackerTable.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;

}
```